# Im trying to format decimal point (x.xx) in Java. I dont understand why an java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.2f'

Tags: java

```
System.out.printf("Spacecraft speed is %.2f" + spacecraftSpeed + "of speed of light, or %.2f" + (spacecraftSpeed/186282) + " Miles/sec.");
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `printf` is that the arguments that it formats are provided separately, rather than added explicitly to the `String`.  What you wanted to write was this.

```
System.out.printf(
    "Spacecraft speed is %.2f of speed of light, or %.2f Miles/sec.", 
    spacecraftSpeed, 
    spacecraftSpeed * 186282);
```

You usually need to provide one additional argument for every format specifier (i.e., the `%.2f` part) in the format string - although there is a way to reuse the arguments.

Note that I've also changed your `/` to a `*` - you convert a fraction of the speed of light into miles per second by multiplying by `186282`, not dividing.  But that's a whole other topic.